# How do I fetch a table inside an entry in PHP firebase?

Tags: php, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After successfully inputting data inside a key, I am now facing the problem of trying to display it.

[image: Table]

this is the code that I've been trying and modifying to try and fetch it but to still to no avail

```
<tr> 
     <th>Course Code</th>
     <th>Discriptive Title</th>
     <th>Unit</th>
     <th>Pre-Requisite</th>
     <th>Grade</th>
 </tr>
 <?php
 include('dbcon.php');
     if(isset($_GET['id']))
      {
         $key_child = $_GET['id'];
         $ref_table = 'User'.$key_child.'/Grades/1st Year/1st Sem';
         $fetchdata = $database->getReference($ref_table)->getChild($key_child)->getValue();
     if($fetchdata > 0)
         {
             $i = 0;
             ?>
              <input type="hidden" name = "id" value = "<?=$key_child;?>">
             <?php
                 foreach($fetchdata as $key_child => $row)
                     {
                     ?>
                 <tr>
                     <td> <?= $row['Course_Code'];?> </td>
                     <td> <?= $row['Desc_title'];?> </td>
                     <td> <?= $row['Unit'];?> </td>
                     <td> <?= $row['Pre-Req'];?> </td>
                     <td> <?= $row['Grade'];?> </td>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                     <?php
         }
     }
     else
     {
         ?>
         <td colspan = "5"> Nothing Found </td>
         <?php
     }
 }
 else
         {
         ?>
             <td colspan = "5"> No Record found </td> 
         <?php
 }
```

**It is displaying the *"Nothing Found"* when I execute it even though there are data in the database.**

And this is the code that I initially tried for some context.

```
 <tr> 
     <th>Course Code</th>
     <th>Discriptive Title</th>
     <th>Unit</th>
     <th>Pre-Requisite</th>
     <th>Grade</th>
 </tr>
$key_child = $_GET['id'];
 $ref_table = 'User'.$key_child.'/Grades/1st Year/1st Sem';
 $getdata = $database->getReference($ref_table)->getChild($key_child)->getValue();
 if($getdata > 0)
 {
  ?>
     <input type="hidden" name = "id" value = "<?=$key_child;?>">
     <tr>
         <td> <?= $row['Course_Code'];?> </td>
         <td> <?= $row['Desc_title'];?> </td>
         <td> <?= $row['Unit'];?> </td>
         <td> <?= $row['Pre-Req'];?> </td>
         <td> <?= $row['Grade'];?> </td>
         </td>
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$key_child` is `5nKX...`, then you're missing a `/` after `User` in this code:

```
$ref_table = 'User'.$key_child.'/Grades/1st Year/1st Sem'
```

So to fix that problem:

```
$ref_table = 'User/'.$key_child.'/Grades/1st Year/1st Sem'
//
```